# Finding a folder with the latest date and output its full name

Tags: powershell

I have a following folder structure:

```
C:\work\settings backup\Backup-26.04.2023_16.36.53
C:\work\settings backup\Backup-26.04.2023_19.08.41
C:\work\settings backup\Backup-28.04.2023_18.42.14
```

I am trying to write a script, which would iterate over the folders inside the "settings backup" folder (the may be tens of them over time), pick the one with the newest date (for the purpose of the demo 28.04.2023_18.42.14), and then output it´s full path name.

That name will be used to get inside (Get-Location/Set-Location), but for the purpose of the demo it is enough if it will displays on the screen.

Currently, it does that only for the last digits, but does not compare the whole date.
Does anybody know how to do that?

````
$RootFolder = "C:\work\settings backup"

$lastFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '(?<=-)\d*.\d*.\d*_\d*.\d*.\d*' } |
    Group-Object -Property @{Expression={ $matches[1] }}  | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={ [int]$matches[2] }} | Select-Object -Last 1
    }

$lastFolder.FullName ```
````

EDIT:// Based on jdweng´s answer, this is the final working code:

````
$RootFolder = "C:\Praca\Vizrt\Mosart settings backup"
$pattern = 'Backup-(?<date>.*)'

$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $pattern}
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($folder in $folders)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Folder -NotePropertyValue $folder.Name
   $folder.Name -match $pattern 
   $date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Matches.Date.Replace('.','_'),'dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss',$null)
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Date -NotePropertyValue $date
   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}

$NewestFolder = $table | Sort-Object -Descending  -Property Date | Select-Object -first 1
Write-host "The latest folder is: " $NewestFolder.Folder

Set-Location (Join-Path $RootFolder -childpath $NewestFolder.Folder) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date with period is an issue.  Also $matches is only getting the last item.  Try following.  You will noeed to sort the table results and get first item.

```
$RootFolder = 'C:\temp'
$pattern = 'Backup-(?<date>.*)'

$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $pattern}
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($folder in $folders)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Folder -NotePropertyValue $folder.Name
   $folder.Name -match $pattern | Out-Null
   $date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Matches.Date.Replace('.','_'),'dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss',$null)
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Date -NotePropertyValue $date
   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}

$table
```

Results :

```
Folder                     Date
------                     ----
Backup-26.04.2023_16.36.53 4/26/2023 4:36:53 PM
Backup-26.04.2023_19.08.41 4/26/2023 7:08:41 PM
Backup-28.04.2023_18.42.14 4/28/2023 6:42:14 PM
```

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented sorting and getting first item + updated the description, it´s working :)